# How can I embed other applications in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created three projects on Visual Studio. One is the base project and I would like to embed the other two projects into the base project. I went through some articles but couldn't find something that suits my requirements (and I am still a newbie in asp.net :)). Below is a screenshot of what I created

[image: VS Solution Explorer Screenshot]

I will like to call `FirstApp` and `SecondApp` when I run the `BaseApp` and also display some unique texts like `"hello from FirstApp"` and `"hello from SecondApp"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to see on a page loaded from a web application another page loaded from a different web application, then you need to use iframes.

To do this you do not need even if the projects are in the same solution. They are different processes. They could even be in different domains. You are really using the http protocol to create the iframes. The applications are completely isolated.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am currently using IFrame but do you know how to make the frame responsive enough it terms of its height and width when the screen resolution changes?

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is create a reference to the projects you want to use, and then call the code in those projects.

You can add a reference to another project by right clicking `BaseApp`, select `Add`, and `Reference`. Then you get a screen where you can select the other projects in your solution. Select the ones you want to use, and you can start to use the classes in the other projects.

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to use FirstApp and SecondApp then create class library of those project and add those library reference in your first project [base].
>   After that you will get all method access in this project based on assembly type.